# SAR processing - geocoding shapefile which is slant range

Tags: shapefile, geocoding, software-recommendations, sar

Is there any software (like snap, sarscape etc.) can be used to geocode shapefile (slant range) to shapefile (ground range) (like WGS84)?

If yes, which data is need for that?

By the way, the shapefile is from Econgnition (not SAR related software).

"geocoding" means that I want to convert a shapefile which is in SAR coordinate system (called slant range) to the real world coordinate system (like WGS84) (called ground range).

Comment: You probably need to define what you mean by "geocode" since this appears to be non-standard usage.

Comment: Sorry for unclear description, "geocode" means that I want to convert a shapefile which is in SAR coordinate system (called slant range) to the real world coordinate system (like WGS84) (called ground range).